# How to properly write Parcelable implementation for an Map<String, Object>?

Tags: android, parcelable

I haven't found a proper answer on the stackoverflow on the same and confused on how to achieve the right Parcelable implementation for an Map .

I suppose for a Map< String , String > below is the correct implementation:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
  out.writeInt(map.size());
  for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()){
    out.writeString(entry.getKey());
    out.writeString(entry.getValue());
  }
}

private MyParcelable(Parcel in){
  //initialize your map before
  int size = in.readInt();
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    String key = in.readString();
    String value = in.readString();
    map.put(key,value);
  }
}
```

**But what about Map < String , Object > ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Because you can't serialize an `Object` into a `Parcel`. If the `Object` in question `implements Parcelable` then you can do something like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
  out.writeInt(map.size());
  for(Map.Entry<String,Parcelable> entry : map.entrySet()){
    out.writeString(entry.getKey());
    entry.getValue().writeToParcel(out, flags);
  }
}

private MyParcelable(Parcel in){
  //initialize your map before
  int size = in.readInt();
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    String key = in.readString();
    Parcelable value = in.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
    map.put(key,value);
  }
}
```

**HOWEVER:** You don't need to do this, because the `Parcel` class already knows how to serialize and unserialize `Map` , provided that the key is a `String` and the value is a "known" object type (includes `Serializable` and `Parcelable`). So you can just do this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags){
    out.writeValue(map);
}


private MyParcelable(Parcel in){
    map = (Map)in.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
}
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue(java.lang.Object) for a list of "known" object types.

**NOTE:** You will get always get a `HashMap` if you call `Parcel.getValue()` on a `Map`. Android is stupid about this and assumes all `Map`s are `HashMap`s.

Comment: Hi @David , thanks for the answer. i tried the first code snippet but it didn't work for me. Also i am confused on how to use the second snippet u shared,  map = in.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());  is not a valid statement according to android studio.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work". Be more specific please. Remote debugging is hard enough without details

Comment: Reagding "not a valid statement", you probably need to cast the returned value. I've updated my answer.